# How to get dependent cells with NPOI Excel .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel, npoi

I have a .NET Core application with NPOI that open an Excel file. 
I need to know all the cell modified after updating a cell value. It's possible? 
Or at least it's possible to get all dependent cells of a particular cell?

Comment: Did you manage to get the dynamic filters in excel? If you have any ideas, I would appreciate if you could share them with me

Comment: I have not found any solution with NPOI.  
I created a new branch and installed Microsoft.Interop.Excel.   
In this branch i created a service that reads all cells and their dependencies, and stored the informations inside a Database.   

Inside the normal application i get the dependencies from the DB and check for each cell if the value is different from the value i have in my DB.